# Passing ArrayList<Double> from one Activity to other activty give data in wrong order

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, double

I am trying to send `ArrayList<double>` from one activity to other activity, but when retrieve arraylist from second activity it give the `arraylist of double` but unfortunately it gives the double arraylist in wrong order or you can say in ascending order. How can I solve it.

```
Example:
         39.7 position 0
         30.5 position 1
         30.3 position 2
     output
         30.3 position 0
         30.5 position 1
         39.7 position 2

 **Add arraylist double**
      intent.putExtra("24data", tmp);

 **retrieve arraylist code**
      for(double d:(ArrayList<Double>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("24data")){
         Log.d("double value", d+"");
      }
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: and how do you build tmp?

Comment: ArrayList<Double> tmp=new ArrayList<Double>();
tmp.add(....);

Comment: Please provide the full code of the insertion. From what you posted here, there is no reason for the items order to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making a deep copy or just pointing to the arraylist? What method are you using for sending the AL to the other activity? Depending on how important minimizing program complexity is to your app, you can always just add a method that inverts your arraylist... (Using a second temp arraylist and a loop for example - you can probably just modify your original "sending" method to do this)

Comment: Thanks solved try to sort arraylist so used ArrayList.clone method to solve problem thank ones agin